# Convert Python string to list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list formatted as shown here:

```
>>> x = "[26, 25]"
>>> list(x)
['[', '2', '6', ',', ' ', '2', '5', ']']
```

How do I convert to a list with elements as shown here:

```
>>> x
[25, 26]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval(x)
```

or treat it as JSON, using [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

json.loads(x)
```

`ast.literal_eval()` takes Python literals as input (so text that in Python source code would give you a value), `json.loads()` takes JSON input.

Demo:

```
>>> import ast, json
>>> x = "[26, 25]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
[26, 25]
>>> json.loads(x)
[26, 25]
```

The difference between the two only comes into play when you have more than a list of integers in your input string; JSON strings contain unicode, which `ast.literal_eval()` on Python 2 would not interpret correctly, and JSON types are only a subset of what `ast.literal_eval()` supports.

```
>>> x = '["List", "with", "strings", "including", "snowman", "\u2603"]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
['List', 'with', 'strings', 'including', 'snowman', '\\u2603']
>>> json.loads(x)
[u'List', u'with', u'strings', u'including', u'snowman', u'\u2603']
>>> x = "(1, 2, 3, 'a tuple is Python syntax, not JSON')"
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
(1, 2, 3, 'a tuple is Python syntax, not JSON')
>>> json.loads(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 2):

another option if you know you are doing the right thing

```
x = "[26, 25]"
y = eval(x)
print y
```

Comment: there is the danger of malicious code injection with this approach - if x is read from a file and a hacker is somehow able to change the file...

Answer (score 0):

Better than "eval" (from the security, and speed (probably) point of view) would be:

```
[int(v) for v in x[1:-1].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
```

Comment: Is this proved to be faster than using the [safe eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: You'd have to `map()` to `int()` as well to get integers.

Comment: @KDawG not proved, by comparing eval in JS I am guessing that it is not too fast...

Comment: @ProblemFactory do you realize python and JS are two HOLY different languages??

Comment: @KDawG do you realize that IDEA is not related to any language? For example, recursion will be more memory consuming than iterating, OOP will be slower than procedural style etc.

Comment: @ProblemFactory we are talking about two HOLY! different languages, python is server side whereas JS is client-side and for all the vast things that python can do JS can't and vice versa, If you had at least picked java I might have agreed.... but JS C'mon!

Comment: @KDawG just think how `eval` could work, it basically run "interpreter" within current Python interpreter, that just is not fast and efficient. 
PS. I suppose you didn't heard about NodeJS...

Comment: I suggest comparing this answer to `eval` using `timeit`. That would pretty well resolve arguments about what's fast :-)

Comment: Nothing holy about JavaScript.  Quite the opposite, in fact.  :-)